# Classpath issue: Gradle not working

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, jar, gradle

Uinsg Gradle on Netbeans 8.02:

Getting the Java compilation error concerning additional libraries not being automatically added to the classpath.

So

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
```

Produces the error

> package org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel does not exist

How does one go about fixing this error?

Edit: The Gradle build file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

// NetBeans will automatically add "run" and "debug" tasks relying on the
// "mainClass" property. You may however define the property prior executing
// tasks by passing a "-PmainClass=<QUALIFIED_CLASS_NAME>" argument.
//
// Note however, that you may define your own "run" and "debug" task if you
// prefer. In this case NetBeans will not add these tasks but you may rely on
// your own implementation.
if (!hasProperty('mainClass')) {
    ext.mainClass = ''
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    // You may define additional repositories, or even remove "mavenCentral()".
    // Read more about repositories here:
    //   http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:repositories
}

dependencies {
    // TODO: Add dependencies here ...
    // You can read more about how to add dependency here:
    //   http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:how_to_declare_your_dependencies
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.10'
}
```

Comment: Can you show us you gradle build file?

Comment: Looks like you should fix you `// TODO: Add dependencies here ...`. See @tinker's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the library dependency in your 'compile' requirements. Read more about dependencies [here](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html). Dependencies can be found in public Maven repositories, or you can add your own if you have a custom repo.